# Laravel 5 - redirect()->intended() after authentication not going to intended

Tags: laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.0's default postAuth, default authentication all around. For some reason, `redirect()->intended()` does not work! Debugging `Session::get('url.intended')` reveals some funky stuff, but don't know if it's normal.

I log out, then try to visit `http://localhost:3000/updates`, which is a valid route. It correctly sends me to `/auth/login`, but once I login it *always* sends me to `/home`. Inside the `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` trait, I put this in:

```
if ($this->auth->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember')))
{
    dd(\Session::get('url.intended'));
    return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

The `dd()` reveals the correct intended path, but with a bunch of junk on the end.

> "//localhost:3000/updates%3C/span%3E"

Doing a `dd(redirect()->intended())` exposes that it is trying to go to that strange url:

```
RedirectResponse {#344 ▼
  #request: Request {#37 ▶}
  #session: Store {#304 ▶}
  #targetUrl: "//localhost:3000/updates%3C/span%3E"
  +headers: ResponseHeaderBag {#346 ▶}
  #content: """
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=//localhost:3000/updates" />

            <title>Redirecting to //localhost:3000/updates</title>%3C/span%3E
        </head>
        <body>
            Redirecting to <a href="//localhost:3000/updates">//localhost:3000/updates</a>.%3C/span%3E
        </body>
    </html>"""
  #version: "1.0"
  #statusCode: 302
  #statusText: "Found"
  #charset: null
}
```

I've tried this with many other routes with the same results. I could have sworn this was working as expected. Any ideas why it would have stopped?

**Update**

Here is the `Authenticate.php` middleware, which is unmodified from Laravel:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
  if ($this->auth->guest())
  {
    if ($request->ajax())
    {
      return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
    }
    else
    {
      return redirect()->guest('auth/login');
    }
  }

  return $next($request);
}
```

**Update 2**

I decided to stop using Browsersync, which I think was the cause for the `</span>`, and started debugging on the regular vhost url. Debugging inside `Illuminate\Routing\Redirector`'s `intended()` method, everything appears as if it should still work right.

```
if ($this->auth->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember')))
{
  dd(redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath()));
  return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Doing that in `postLogin()` still reveals a seemingly correct response:

```
RedirectResponse {#346 ▼
  #request: Request {#37 ▶}
  #session: Store {#288 ▶}
  #targetUrl: "http://sum.dev/updates"
  +headers: ResponseHeaderBag {#348 ▼
    #computedCacheControl: array:1 [▶]
    #cookies: []
    #headerNames: array:3 [▶]
    #headers: array:3 [▼
      "cache-control" => array:1 [▶]
      "date" => array:1 [▶]
      "location" => array:1 [▼
        0 => "http://sum.dev/updates"
      ]
    ]
    #cacheControl: []
  }
  #content: """
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://sum.dev/updates" />

            <title>Redirecting to http://sum.dev/updates</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            Redirecting to <a href="http://sum.dev/updates">http://sum.dev/updates</a>.
        </body>
    </html>"""
  #version: "1.0"
  #statusCode: 302
  #statusText: "Found"
  #charset: null
}
```

Doing this:

```
if ($this->auth->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember')))
{
  return redirect(\Session::get('url.intended'));
}
```

Works exactly as I would expect the original `return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath())`. Hardcoding the path, `return redirect()->intended('/updates')`, sends me to `/updates`. It makes me think the default path parameter is causing issues, but doing dump of the entire response looks sound. I'm completely baffled. There has to be something I'm missing.

Comment: If you `urldecode()` your intended route you get `localhost:3000/updates</span>`. Check the `href` attribute on your link. Find out where that closing span tag is coming from.

Comment: Can you show your middleware which redirects you to login page?

Comment: @BrokenBinary I'm not clicking any link, but going directly to the url.

Comment: @DanielAntos Updated with the middleware, which is the what ships with Laravel

Comment: It was my own dumb middleware!