# Laravel redirect()->intended() is not working in custom login controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I have a custom login controller and its using  `return redirect()->intended(route('home'))` , as per the documentation this should send the user redirect the user to the URL they were attempting to access before being intercepted by the authentication middleware.

But for my case every time it is redirecting to `home route`.I am sure i have done correctly or at least i think i have done correctly. Can anyone please tell me where i am doing this wrong ??

My `logincontroller` is like this:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

 public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255',
            'password' => 'required|max:255',
        ]);
        try {
            $response = HelperFunctions::fetchData('post', 'login/login', [
                'loginId' => $request->get('email'),
                'password' => md5($request->get('password'))
            ]);
            if ($response['code'] == 200 && $response['success']) {
                session([
                    'api_token' => $response['sessionId'],
                    'user_data' => $response['data']['profile']
                ]);

                return redirect()->intended(route('home'));
            } else {
                return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Please provide valid credentials');
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Opps!! Something is wrong. We are trying to fix it');
        }
```

My authentication checking middleware

```
class checkAuthentication
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        //check if user is logged in
        if(Session::has('api_token') && Session::has('user_data')) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return redirect(route('login'));

    }
}
```

I also tried to `dd()` `Session::get('url.intended')` but it returns empty .

I did tried looking for reference on google, laracast & stackoverflow i found some reference , but those did not help me. Can anyone please help me thank you.

Some of the reference i have checked & tried:

1. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/redirect-intended-not-working-after-login?page=1
2. [Laravel 5 - redirect()->intended() after authentication not going to intended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31018921/laravel-5-redirect-intended-after-authentication-not-going-to-intended)
3. https://laravel.io/forum/11-24-2014-problems-with-redirectintended-and-auth

Comment: Are you using the default auth middleware that comes with Laravel or have you created your own?

Comment: I have created my own middleware

Comment: Since this is total custom login and it is not using laravel default database, so i think those middleware will not work. That is why

Comment: Can you add the code for the middleware your using?

Comment: yes, i have added now in the question

Comment: Thanks. Also, what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I am using `laravel 5.6`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simplest way would be to `redirect()->guest()` in your `Auth` middleware instead of the redirect you currently have:

```
return redirect()->guest(route('login'));
```

Using the `guest()` method on the redirector is what adds the `url.intended` value to the session.

---

Alternatively, instead of returning from the middleware if they're not authenticated you could throw an `AuthenticationException`:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    //check if user is logged in
    if(Session::has('api_token') && Session::has('user_data')) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    throw new AuthenticationException('Unauthenticated.');
}
```

This will allow you to take advantage of Laravel's `ExceptionHandler` if you need to. You will also need to add `use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;` to the top of your class.

Comment: @user7747472 I've also added an alternative but unless you need to hook into Laravel's `ExceptionHandler` then I would just stick with `redirect()->guest()` for now.

Comment: oh okay , what is the best case for using the exception . and do i have to handle it somewhere or it handle automatically ??

Comment: @user7747472 It will get handled automatically with Laravel, however, you can override how it gets handled in your `app/Exceptions/Handler`. If you don't have a need/reason to use the exception handling then I wouldn't worry about it. I just thought I'd mention it incase you did use it in your usual workflow or (for whatever reason) it came up later down the line.

Comment: Your first answer doesn't say what part of the `handle` method should be omitted or overwritten

Comment: @IWantAnswers Sorry, you're right. The redirect login part in my answer should replace the redirect login part of the OP's auth middleware. I hadn't put it in my answer as it's the only part of the middleware that has a redirect. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Idk what version of the Authenticate middleware you're looking at, but I've seen both 5.8 and 6.0 and none have a redirect in their handle methods. What they do have is the regular `next` call middlewares have. Do you mind posting the complete function like you did for your 2nd answer? I can see from the source that the `guest` method is what sets the 'url.intended' key but curious to see where it should be called. In my own answer, I don't use it but it works all the same

Comment: @IWantAnswers You won't find this specific middleware in any Laravel version as the auth middleware this question is talking about is bespoke and specific to the OP's application. If you are having any issues yourself I would suggest opening a new question as this one it somewhat specific to the OP's situation rather than a general how-to with Laravel. Lastly, just as an FYI, at the time of posting the OP was using Laravel 5.6.

Answer (score 0):

> I also tried to dd() Session::get('url.intended') but it returns empty .

In my case, this key existed in my session, but for some weird reason, something funny happens after `redirect()->intended()` returns the redirect response. Maybe the response is discarded in transit, or intercepted by some other caller on the stack.

What I did to work around it was to manually obtain the intended url from the session and hand it over to the redirect (instead of relying on the underlying protocols of `intended()`).

By adding this

```
redirect(Session::get('url.intended', $this->redirectPath()));
```

at the bottom of `LoginController@showLoginResponse`, once user is authenticated, Laravel is able to remember intended url and redirect to it

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this problem and the best way I come up with is using the authenticated method.

So Override the authenticated method in your controller and use the intended route there.

```
 /**
 * The user has been authenticated.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  mixed  $user
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if ($user->role == 'admin') {
        return redirect()->intended('/admin');
    } elseif ($user->role == 'user') {
        return redirect()->intended('/');
    }
}
```

also sometimes changing the RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware also helps.
so go to App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated.php and edit it as well.

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {

            if ($request->user()->role == 'admin') {
                return redirect()->intended('/admin');
            } elseif ($request->user()->role == 'user') {
                return redirect()->intended('/');
            }
            // return redirect('/home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do this:

> return redirect()->intended('home');

Instead of this:

> return redirect()->intended(route('home'));

Comment: Yes i tried, but it is also  sending to `home` instead of user intended route